# Swift iOS Firebase Google authentication with Google Console OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-oauth, google-developers-console

How can we configure the custom created **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** in the **google console** to our **firebase project**?

Our Firebase project is implementing google authentication in an iOS app.
Everything works properly:

- added URL schemes
- added .plist provided by firebase

[image]

In order to register our app through google we have to implement custom

**OAuth 2.0 Client IDs**

[image]

**Problem:**

How can we properly use the custom (google console) OAuth 2.0 Client ID in the firebase project? Do I need to use the new plist provided in the google console?